# Updating registry value from cmd line if the value is already present InstallSheild

Tags: installshield

I have an InstallSheild msi that creates a registry key and adds a value to it. It doesn't get removed on the uninstall, because we like that functionality of remembering the value between upgrades.

My question is how can I override that value if I run the installer via command line and pass in a new value?

Right now it does a system search to find the value and if it exist it will use that one regardless of what you pass in from the cmd line parameter. I was hoping I could add a condition in somewhere to state if its in the cmd line use that instead of the old value.

Comment: How do you currently add the value? If it's handled in a custom action, could that action check for the different combinations of registry present / command line (property) present, and do the right thing?

Comment: It doesn't use a custom action from what I can tell. I'm new to installers so I could be wrong, but the UI just takes the text from the text box and puts it in a property then that property is put into a registry key as a component. What confuses me is why it accepts the cmd line if its a fresh install, but ignores it if it already exist.

Comment: That would explain why it doesn't overwrite (if the component's there, it won't reinstall it and thus won't rewrite the key), but doesn't explain how it persists after uninstall. Unless the component it's in is permanent, in which case I don't think there are any clean answers.

Comment: Yes its a permanent component. So there isn't a way to overwrite the value without uninstalling it and reinstalling the component?

Answer (score 0):

one way to do it is something like that.

1. make your system search place the value in a temporary value.
2. then make a custom action that run right after you system search, that replace your value with the temporary value, if it hasn't already been set via the cmdline.